# VGA to HDMI adapter - modifying config.txt

Tags: noobs, config.txt

I have a pre-installed micro SD card with NOOBs. But the instructions on the internet say to use a HDMI to VGA cable, I need to un-comment two lines of code in the config.txt file:

```
#hdmi_force_hotplug =1
#hdmi_drive =2
```

I cannot find any config.txt file on my pre-installed files that comes with the canakit. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When booting the Pi you need to hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key.

This boots the Pi into recovery mode and you will be able to access the config.txt file as shown in the picture below. There's a different config.txt file for each OS, so you need to select the OS you are using.

[image]

For future reference if you are not using a NOOBs install:

Open a terminal window and run the following command:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

This will open the config.txt file in an editor called nano. If you scroll through the text file you should be able to find the two lines:

```
#hdmi_force_hotplug =1
#hdmi_drive =2
```

Removing the `#` un-comments those lines. After doing that you need to exit the file with saving.

Comment: You presumably have not tried NOOBS - there is **NO config.txt** on the boot partition (as distinct from that mounted on `/boot` after running Raspbian)

Comment: @Milliways I've edited the answer to reflect that.